# Entity framework, remove entity if it detached from another entity

Tags: entity-framework

I have model with relation:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
      .HasMany(p => p.Properties)
      .WithOptional();
```

For examle, Product1 have 3 Property, and when I remove one property from product (not from db) I want to delete it in db, because it does not used anywhere anymore.
Can I do this by using EF?

Answer (score 0):

If your navigational properties are not virtual:

```
using(var db = new YourDbContext()
{
var product = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => ...);
product.Properties.RemoveAll(x => ...);
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Otherwise:

```
using(var db = new YourDbContext()
{
var product = db.Products.Include("Properties").FirstOrDefault(x => ...);
product.Properties.RemoveAll(x => ...);
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Can EF do this automatically?

Comment: When you load something from the database, EF uses in memory cache where it retains all the relationships - it's called object tracking. It is turned on by the default. If you remove some entity from collection that is defined in another entity, EF will notice that. Once you do a call to SaveChanges(), all changes in object tracking will be persisted in the database.